next js static build css, js path problem
next.js static build and download
local open html
Error Image:

After next.js static build, css and js path starts with file:///.
I want to change the path please.
-- next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    loader: "custom",
    loaderFile: "localImageLoader.js"
  },
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./"));

    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig

I also tried assetprfix: "./" or basepath: "./", but an error occurred because they did not start with /.

Welcome to StackOverflow. You should use a server to serve your app, so no path starts with file:///. It's not surprising that you encounter problems when trying to open a nextjs app with no server running because the whole point of nextjs is serverside rendering and executing logic on the server. Probably you have to run npm run build and then npm start from your project directory. You could also try next build and next start. Take a look into your package.json file.

Try this:
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    loaderFile: 'localImageLoader.js',
  },
  assetPrefix: '', // Set to '' for relative paths, or a specific URL base if needed
  basePath: '', // No base path
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'));

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

ref links:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/assetPrefix
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath

